# Automatically create an account from specific Web-to-Lead forms

Tags: web2lead

Within our Web-to-Lead forms we use a hidden form field to identify the forms location. Is it possible to automatically convert certain leads (if the hidden form field matches our requirements) directly into a new account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use a trigger on lead that automatically converts the lead based on the  field value.

NOTE: This trigger was written to show you the general idea. I haven't tested it in practice.

```
trigger convertLead on Lead (after insert) {

    LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];

    List<Database.LeadConvert> conversions = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();

    for(Lead l : Trigger.new) {
        // This is where you can test your hidden field requirements.
        if(l.CustomField__c == 'convertCondition') {
            Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
            lc.setLeadId(l.Id);
            lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(True);
            lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

            // Use List to bulkify conversion process rather than doing one at a time
            conversions.add(lc);
            //Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
            //System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
        }
    }

    if(conversions.size() > 0) {
        List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcrs = Database.convertLead(lc);
    }
}
```